# Log WinForms application state

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, out-of-memory

We have a WinForms application which occationally throws OutOfMemory exceptions. We have been unable to produce this error on any development machine, but it occationally happens for a few of our customers. I am certain that this is not caused by a memory leak, but rather the application trying to handle too much data. This makes sense as only a few of the largest customers are experiencing this issue. The problem, however, is that I have no idea what they are doing when this happens. We have tried asking them and the answer is something like "It just happens some times.". We have an exception reporting service which logs all unhandled exceptions happening in production, but because of how running out of memory works, the culprit is not necessarily in the call stack. I have never seen any of our code in the call stack for these issues.

Is there a way to determine what is going on in an application when these exceptions are thrown? Things like what windows are open and which(how much) information is displayed in the controls of those windows etc.

Here are some example call stacks:

> Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
>   System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc():436
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state):20
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx):112
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx):0
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state):43
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart():8

--

> Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCodeBase(RuntimeAssembly
>   assembly, Boolean copiedName, StringHandleOnStack retString):-1
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCodeBase(Boolean copiedName):0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetName(Boolean copiedName):0
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetName():0
>   System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog..ctor(Exception t):1033
>   System.Windows.Forms.Application+ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception
>   t):57 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(Exception e):0
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception
>   e):0 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam):58

Comment: You can setup [procdump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procdump) to run as a debugger on the customer machine and write a full memory dump of crashing processes. You can then load this dump into Visual Studio on the development machine and can inspect the state of the application using the Visual Studio Debugger.

Comment: Large customers? - are they using Virtual Machines? They are often not set up with much memory compared to a physical PC. Ask them what configuration they are using and have a go at emulating something similar in your own VM-ware, although you'll never replicate their gold-build VM's exactly. Just a thought

Comment: In my experience, OutOfMemory  exceptions in .NET are never even about memory. They are either COM or GDI calls that fail. Apparently, the error codes returned are something .NET doesn't understand so it uses OutOfMemory exception.

Comment: A big reason for OOMs is code that allocates a *lot* of temporary objects, fragmenting memory so badly that the memory allocator can't find enough space to allocate for a new object. Lists for example store items in arrays they have to reallocate each time they are full.  Adding 1M items to a list one by one for example will results in 20 reallocations, using 2M*type-size bytes. A 1M item List<int> constructed item by item will consume 8MB. Creating a list with a big enough `capacity` will reduce reallocations dramatically.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's true, but if that was the source of the problem, shouldn't our code show up in the call stack?

Comment: @JoakimM.H. probably, probably not. *Where is that call stack*? Without concrete information all one can do is tell you to profile the application. You can start by gathering performance counters on the affected machines, eg memory counters, GDI counters, .NET specific counters like GCs, generations, allocations etc.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. you can also integrate StackOverflow's own [MiniProfiler](https://miniprofiler.com/dotnet/ConsoleDotNet) in desktop applications and have it gather extra performance information. *Crash Dump* can be loaded into Visual Studio and allow you to debug an application as if it was running locally, see threads, stacks etc. That assumes you have the source code and pdbs that correspond to the production code.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. another option is [Logary](https://github.com/logary/logary) a logging framework similar to log4net and Serilog that *also* gathers metrics like perf counters. That's extremely useful when trying to track multiple instances, like service instances or multiple applications.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. going a bit further, you can record IntelliTrace events on a production machine and use them to use Historical Debuggint in your application as shown in [Diagnose problems after deployment using IntelliTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/diagnose-problems-after-deployment?view=vs-2017). Never mind the TFS/Monitoring Agent blurb, you can add this to any kind of build. Next level, use the free tier of Application Insights/Azure Monitor to collect traces, even detect problems in advance

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I updated the question with some example call stacks. There are 65 unique call stacks for OutOfMemoryException in our error logging system the last 6 months. Most of them only have one ocurrence. I don't really think the call stacks are that important, since they just show the straw that broke the camels back.

I'll look into those options, but I would rather not have to install debugging software on customer machines.

Comment: @JoakimM.H. `System.Net.TimerThread.ThreadProc(..` , `WaitHandle.WaitAny`  `Forms.NativeWindow.Callback` are you using any *Winforms* timers? What do they do? Is the code creating new Timer objects all the time but not disposing them perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there are several timers used for different things. Some are used to delay saving to the database until you've stopped typing for a couple seconds, some are used to refresh data every N minutes. All timers are created when the form they belong to is opened and disposed when it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best explanation for what this isn't is found here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory/

The basic idea is, that in modern Windows OS, the computer will sieze up and die before it runs out of memory. It would need to consume every byte of the hard disk and it would swap so badly you'd notice terrible slowdowns long before actually running out of memory.

So, what is an "OutOfMemoryException" and why do they happen? Well, there are a few causes, somewhat related to memory, and some causes that have nothing at all to do with memory.

The most common source of this error: GDI+ calls with bad parameters.  Any error from GDI+, including using System.Drawing libraries, throws OutOfMemoryException. That seems to be because the underlying API doesn't give any information to .NET about why it failed, so the creators of .NET decided to call them all OutofMemoryException and now they are stuck with it for compatibility.  Things like trying to create a 0 size pen or create a bitmap with bad format flags result in "Out of Memory"

The reason .NET may have used OutOfMemory for GDI errors is that a lot of the errors actually are somewhat memory related. There is still a limited number of GDI handles available. It may be a couple million, but still limited, so if something is leaking an underlying HBITMAP or HBRUSH or HPEN, eventually it runs out, GDI calls fail, and you get an exception.

The other place I've seen the error is using any COM interface. If a COM object returns an error, you may get an OutOfMemory exception. I try to catch and handle those errors.

For tracing, look at your GDI/System.Drawing related calls. Look at stack trace, it is showing you the problem.

Also, don't assume that an "OutOfMemory" error needs to shut down the application. You should be able to recover just fine from those exceptions because you aren't really out of memory. Why does the customer even see this error?

Comment: That last sentence is what I'm trying to find out.

The application is an administrative tool for our main application, and is basically used to view and edit the database. My initial thought was that too much data was being fetched from the database and some collection tried to store it all in one contiguous array - causing an out of memory exception because no free memory slots were large enough. Then I realized that if that was the case, our code - which did the loading of the data from the database - should appear in the call stack. It does not.

Comment: List reallocations, string splits can also cause OOMs due to the memory fragmentation they cause

Comment: @JoakimM.H. don't be so sure. Adding 1M items one by one to a List<int> will cause 20 reallocations of the internal buffer. The 1045505th item will result in a new *2097152*-long buffer. Do that in a tight loop and the GC won't have time to clean them up. All those reallocations can fragment memory so badly there's no large enough memory block for a new big buffer

Comment: fragmentation of address space is possible in 32bit. In 64bit app, that's highly unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: @JoakimM.H.  Do you check the InnerException on the exception object?

Comment: My question about why the customer sees it is if you are catching the exception to log the error, why also display it to the user?  I suppose you could try to do a screen grab at the time you catch the error and save it as a JPG

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes - there is no inner exception.

The customer sees this because we've got handlers for Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException which send the error to our error logging system, and shows the user a "Something went wrong"-popup which is more user friendly that Windows' "Application has stopped working.".

Comment: is application 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey the application is 32 bit.

Comment: In that case I'd look for a real leak. You have a 4GB limit.  Maybe add some periodic checks on the Process object (VirtualMemorySize64, PeakVirtualMemorySize64, etc.). Best to call after collecting garbage.